# Iterating through LinkedHashMap Values Isn't Ordered?

Tags: java, arrays, linkedhashmap, key-value-store, toarray

For a problem I'm designing in Java, I'm given a list of dates and winning lottery numbers. I'm supposed to do things with them, and spit them back out in order. I decided to choose a LinkedHashMap to solve it, the Date containing the date, and int[] containing the array of winning numbers.

Thing is, when I run the .values() function, I'm noticing the numbers are no longer ordered (by insertion). The code I'm running is:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){ //testing first 30 to see if ordered
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString((int [])(winningNumbers.values().toArray()[i])));
    }
```

Can anyone see what exactly I'm doing wrong? Tempted almost to just use .get() and iterate through the dates, since the dates do go in some order, but that might make using a LinkedHashMap moot. Might as well be using a 2-D ArrayList[][] in that case. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Adding code for further examination!

Lottery Class: http://pastebin.com/9ezF5U7e
Text file: http://pastebin.com/iD8jm7f8

To test, call checkOldLTNums(). Just pass it any int[] array, it doesn't utilize it, at least relevant to this problem. The output is different from the first lines in the .txt, which is organized. Thanks!

EDIT2:

I think I figured out why it fails. I used a smaller .txt file, and the code worked perfectly. It might be that it isn't wise to load 1900 entries of stuff into memory. I suppose it's better to just load individual lines and compare them instead of grabbing everything at once. Is this logic sound? Any advice going from here would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

The `values()` method will return the `Map`'s values *in the same order they were inserted*, that's what *ordered* means, don't confuse it with *sorted*, that means a different thing - that the items follow the ordering defined by the value's `Comparator` or its natural ordering if no comparator was provided.

Perhaps you'd be better off using a `SortedMap` that keeps the items sorted by key. To summarise: `LinkedHashMap` is *ordered* and `TreeMap` is *sorted*.

Comment: I apologize, I should have been more careful with how I worded things. My problem is that regardless, they don't appear in the same order they were inserted. .values() is yielding a random sort of my map instead of by insertion order.

Comment: @Luiserebii try using `entrySet()` or `keySet()` to iterate over the `Map`.

Comment: Hmm, just checked keySet, and the keys are out of insertion order as well. Any ideas as to why this might be happening? Should I upload my code somewhere?

Comment: The only possible explanation is that you're not actually using a LinkedHashMap, because the behavior you're describing doesn't correspond with the class contract. Check the part where you're instantiating the LinkedHashMap, make sure that you're not copying data to a different Map, etc.

Comment: Hmm, here's my instantiation:

Map<Date,int[]> winningNumbers = new LinkedHashMap<Date,int[]>();

Comment: @Luiserebii, you should provide your whole code then, because something has to be going wrong in the middle somewhere.

Comment: Looks good, dates in `winningNumbers` _have to appear_ in the same order they were inserted. Better write a standalone example showing the problem, because I can't think of any other way to help you.

Comment: Ok! Here's my code: 

Lottery Class: http://pastebin.com/9ezF5U7e
Text file: http://pastebin.com/iD8jm7f8

To test, call checkOldLTNums(). Just pass it any int[] array, it doesn't utilize it, at least relevant to this problem.

Comment: You're only adding `tempArrList.get(0)`, what about the rest of the elements in `tempArrList`? Also, the way you're iterating over the `values()` is incorrect, use an iterator, there's no need to convert the values to an array.

Comment: tempAttList.get(0) is only referenced to extract the date. For the rest of the elements, please see the following for loop, which puts them into finalInt[]. As for the iteration over values, I am unfamiliar with an iterator?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Wait, what were you talking about with using an iterator? Perhaps that is the key to my problem, how do you iterate properly? Link would be most helpful :)

Comment: I don't think so, the code to fill the Map seems more likely to be causing the problem, but it's too messy to understand. Start from the beginning, write a little example, see that it works and then start refactoring your code until it works like the little example

Comment: I think I figured out why it fails. I used a smaller .txt file, and the code worked perfectly. It might be that it isn't wise to load 1900 entries of stuff into memory. I suppose it's better to just load individual lines and compare them instead of grabbing everything at once. Is this logic sound? Any advice going from here would be useful.

Comment: After further examination, I've realized that some of the keys for Date is replacing others for some reason. I'll try to figure that issue out now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `TreeMap` instead. You should get the values in ascending key order that way.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I missed this. I did some more troubleshooting, and realized some of the Date keys were replacing others. After doing some testing, I finally realized that the formatting I was using was off: "dd/MM/yyyy" instead of "MM/dd/yyyy". That's what I get for copy-pasting, haha. Thanks to all who helped!